# Is there an Python Function from which we can audit all the website opened in a ".txt" file while closing the browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webbrowser-control

I am trying to log all the websites I have opened in a text file while closing the browsers using Python. Are there any python methods to get the URL from the browser? I am using "webbrowser" package.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share the code you have already figured out.

Comment: Hi Hardik, I just don't have any idea how to get the data from the web browser. But, I   have the code to open the sites within the text file using webbrowser in python.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a basic program that can access browser history for Chrome on Windows 10 using just `os and sqlite3` libraries. There shouldn't be much difference for other browsers and operating systems.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import sqlite3

def parse(url):
    try:

        parsed_url_components = url[0].split('//')

        sublevel_split = parsed_url_components[1].split('/', 1)
        domain = sublevel_split[0].replace("www.", "")
        # You can write the visited URL to a text file
        print(domain)
    except IndexError:
        print("URL format error!")

data_path = os.path.expanduser('~') + "/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default"
files = os.listdir(data_path)
history_db = os.path.join(data_path, 'history')

c = sqlite3.connect(history_db)
cursor = c.cursor()
select_statement = "SELECT urls.url, urls.visit_count FROM urls, visits WHERE urls.id = visits.url;"
cursor.execute(select_statement)

results = cursor.fetchall()
for result in results:
    parse(result)
```

You can choose to avoid doing a sublevel split or www replacement.

PS: The browser must not be running, or you will not be able to access the sqlite db (Error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`)

Hope it helps!